# Not picking up the correct GCC verison

Tags: linux, gcc

I am running an environment which requires an older version of `gcc` (`gcc.4.8.3` to be exact).

I have this version of gcc sitting at location: `/usr/local/bin` (see below)

[image]

I have appended `/usr/local/bin` to my `$PATH` file so that this directory is checked for a version of `gcc` first - so picking up the `gcc.4.8.3` version (see below)

[image]

However when I check the version of `gcc` I still see the latest version gcc.4.9.3 referenced and not `gcc.4.8.3`.(see below)

[image]

How can I reference version `gcc.4.8.3` using my `$PATH` file?

Comment: Just use `gcc-4.8.3` instead of plain `gcc`. (And 4.9 is only slightly less obsolete than 4.8, not the "latest version" or even close to...)

Comment: [ubuntu: How to choose the default gcc and g++ version?](https://askubuntu.com/a/26518/186864)

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)